# Use @decorators in Bicep for params of type object?

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

With a "simple" param in Bicep, I can use @decorators for some sort of "validation", like so:

```
@minLength(3)
@maxLength(20)
@description('Name of database administrator')
param dbAdminUsername string = 'dbadmin'
```

This would force the `dbAdminUsername` param to be between 3 and 20 chars and also show a description.

I'd like to "group together" all the params that I have for databases; like username, password, server name, database name, etc.pp.. So I'd define an object:

```
param db object = {
  adminName: 'dbadmin'
  serverName: 'foo'
  size: 42
  // ...
}
```

A few questions reg. objects:

- Can I somehow use decorators for the various properties that I might have?
- What about defining the types for the allowed values (int, bool, string, ...)?
- And how to define REQUIRED values? With the definition shown above, I define some default values. That's not always what is wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not possible (yet). There’s ongoing discussion how to define such conditions: https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/622

Any additional input is welcome!

Comment: Darn. Okay, thanks. So I guess I won't be using objects but just "normal" variables" instead.

Comment: Variables does not have types also. They have implicit typing, so if a variable is coming from param object property it's effective type is `any`. I personally use params with objects, describe type in metadata (for human purposes only) and I'm waiting for strong object types :)